# Tilde (~) symbol on Django regex url (Cookiecutter Django)

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

After installing  [Cookiecutter Django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) i saw the tilde (~) symbol in regex and don't know the meaning for url purposes.

It's related to a regular expression or only a way to declare paths?

./users/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(
        regex=r'^~redirect/$',
    ...
    url(
        regex=r'^~update/$',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` does not have any special meaning in a regular expression. The url pattern matches the path `/~redirect/` literally.

Comment: @Nadav Not a clue.